# Como remover ultimo elemento de uma lista encadeada usando posição?

Tags: java, lista-encadeada

Estou querendo remover o ultimo elemento de uma lista encadeada digitando a posição n:

quando digito 1,2,3,4,5 do e n=2, quero que fique 1,2,3,5 mas esta dando 1,2,3.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class No {
    int val;
    No prox;

    No(int x) {
        val = x;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static No removeNElementoDoFim(No cabeca, int n) {

        if (cabeca == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            No ultimoNo = cabeca.prox;
            No penultimoNo = cabeca.prox;
            for (int i = 0; ultimoNo.prox != null && i < n; i++) {
                penultimoNo = ultimoNo;
                ultimoNo = ultimoNo.prox;
            }
            penultimoNo.prox = null;
            return cabeca;
        }

    }

    public static int[] stringToIntegerArray(String input) {
        input = input.trim();
        if (input.length() == 0) {
            return new int[0];
        }

        String[] parts = input.split(",");
        int[] output = new int[parts.length];
        for (int index = 0; index < parts.length; index++) {
            if (parts[index].trim().length() > 0) {
                String part = parts[index].trim();
                output[index] = Integer.parseInt(part);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static No stringToNo(String input) {

        int[] nodeValues = stringToIntegerArray(input);

        No root = new No(0);
        No ptr = root;
        for (int item : nodeValues) {
            ptr.prox = new No(item);
            ptr = ptr.prox;
        }
        return root.prox;
    }

    public static String noToString(No no) {
        if (no == null) {
            return "[]";
        }

        String result = "";
        while (no != null) {
            result += Integer.toString(no.val) + ", ";
            no = no.prox;
        }
        return "[" + result.substring(0, result.length() - 2) + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scann = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;
        while (scann.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scann.nextLine();
            No cabeca = stringToNo(line);

            int n = Integer.valueOf(scann.nextLine());

            No ret = removeNElementoDoFim(cabeca, n);

            String out = noToString(ret);

            System.out.print(out);
        }

        scann.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom, vamos lá. Estou considerando que seja uma lista encadeada simples.
Irei lhe dizer a lógica:

Dentro do método que irá receber um valor n, você irá:
 1. Verificar se a lista não está vazia
 2. Se você tiver feito um atributo para o tamanho da lista, verifique se o valor digitado é menor ou igual o tamanho (considerando que o usuário digite 0 para o primeiro valor).
 3. Se sim, for menor, você irá fazer o seguinte:
 4. Criar um novo ponteiro auxiliar recebendo o inicio (fazemos isso para não ter que alterar o ponteiro início), exemplo:

```
no *aux = inicio;

int i;
for(i=0;i<posicao-1;i++) {
   aux = aux.prox;
}
```

Agora, precisaremos atualizar os ponteiros:

```
aux.next = aux.next.next;
tam--;
```

Como no java tem "coletor de lixo", não precisaremos excluir o aux que criamos.

Você pode incluir isso no começo:

```
   if(posicao<tam && posicao>=0){
     if(posicao==0){
         removerinicio();
   }
```

Caso o usuário digite 0!
Abraços!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, mas não da maneira correta:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class No {
    int val;
    No prox;

    No(int x) {
        val = x;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static No removeNElementoDoFim(No cabeca, int n) {

        // Coloque seu código aqui
        No aux = cabeca;
        if (cabeca == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                aux.prox.prox.prox = aux.prox.prox.prox.prox;
            }

            return aux;
        }
    }

    public static int[] stringToIntegerArray(String input) {
        input = input.trim();
        if (input.length() == 0) {
            return new int[0];
        }

        String[] parts = input.split(",");
        int[] output = new int[parts.length];
        for (int index = 0; index < parts.length; index++) {
            if (parts[index].trim().length() > 0) {
                String part = parts[index].trim();
                output[index] = Integer.parseInt(part);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static No stringToNo(String input) {

        int[] nodeValues = stringToIntegerArray(input);

        No root = new No(0);
        No ptr = root;
        for (int item : nodeValues) {
            ptr.prox = new No(item);
            ptr = ptr.prox;
        }
        return root.prox;
    }

    public static String noToString(No no) {
        if (no == null) {
            return "[]";
        }

        String result = "";
        while (no != null) {
            result += Integer.toString(no.val) + ", ";
            no = no.prox;
        }
        return "[" + result.substring(0, result.length() - 2) + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scann = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;
        while (scann.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scann.nextLine();
            No cabeca = stringToNo(line);

            int n = Integer.valueOf(scann.nextLine());

            No ret = removeNElementoDoFim(cabeca, n);

            String out = noToString(ret);

            System.out.print(out);
        }

        scann.close();
    }
}
```